# Is there any way to cancel pending transaction in CCvault or any cardano wallets

Tags: wallet, ccvault

Hi i was swapping in sundaeswap and price went too far but my transaction is still pending in ccvault so can i cancel or remove pending transaction in ccvault before it goes to order and cancelling order with another fees.

Comment: I'd also like to know, I've just found out an address I've sent to is a scam address. How can I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try spending the same utxo the first transaction did and see if that one gets adopted in a block. If it does, that would make that one null and void. Also worth checking TTL on initial tx. It might already have failed and ccvault doesn't have TTL checking in it (I'm not aware of their design, just speculation on why it didn't get added to a block).